# It there standard algorithm or their combination for conditional replacing adjacent repeating values?

Tags: c++, search, replace, std

**Functional specification**

In case in the vector the value adjacently repeated more than **repetitions** times and this value is not excluded by some **predicate**, replace all the repeated values with a new specified value.

Please see the fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nWfMdqcz3).

Please don't pay much attention to the code, no need to optimize it, it provided for explanation purposes only.

**Question**

Is there a way to express this in terms of C++ Standard Library algorithms using one of combination of them to make this code more generic and avoid reinventing the wheel?

**The code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool pred(int value) { const int excluder = 1; return value == excluder; }

void replace_repeating(int* first, int* last, const auto& pred, size_t repetitions, int replacement) {
    size_t count = 0;
    for (; first < last; ++first) {
        if (*first == *(first+1)) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            if (count >= repetitions && !pred(*first)) {
                std::fill(first - count +1 , first +1, replacement);
            }
            count = 1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6 };
    size_t repetitions = 3;
    int replacement = 0;

    replace_repeating(v.data(), v.data()+v.size(), pred, repetitions, replacement);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Performance is critical, so it would be nice to avoid excessive work. (The vector expected to be large enough, gigabytes).

I am going to use execution policies, so usage of ranges is under question.

Comment: Your "replace_repeating" function should create dynamic allocated array's or vectors for each sign / character to store positions of the repeating the indexes and use the newly created vectors or array to remove / replace them in the original one.

Comment: Judging from your code only adjacent repetitions matter?

Comment: @alagner, yes. Thank you for catching this; title and functional specification have been updated.

Comment: @NaturalDemon, as I said beneath the code "Performance is critical, so it would be nice to avoid excessive work.". Any such allocations will cause significant performance degradation, I guess. In case you can show such an algorithm that won't, please share.

Comment: @DamirTenishev is the vector supposed to be sorted in the real case, or does it happen to be sorted only in your example?

Comment: @alagner, the vector is not supposed to be sorted, thank you for catching this. I've updated the example to make it explicit.

Comment: @DamirTenishev so you want the duplicated values outside the first occurrence to be substituted with a new value? what value?

Comment: @DamirTenishev have a look here, please https://quick-bench.com/q/ImqzfOUp7N_Q-culdHBDoj7pQIA Now, the possibility exists I did overlook sth (blame the late night ;)), but the results vary depending if GCC or Clang is used. In both cases though, the best I could get with STL is about 10% slower than the bare loop. Clang for some reason optimizes iterator based loop better. Now, if that readability is worth the speed - I don't know your exact case; I can only guess it's not.

Comment: @NaturalDemon, the value is the last function parameter, **replacement**. Isn't this obvious from its name and usage in `std::fill`?

Comment: @alagner: In your "std" version, you change condition order call (predicate before repetition count), especially with your data, chance are that numbers != 1 count are bigger than number of repetition >= 3 (chance than 3 numbers ([-100; 99]) are equals  is 1/40'000, so your sample might have around 5 repetitions case). With OP data, timing are different [Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/eb0z4XH9GhmNVXavk0eTpCgaETg)

Comment: @Jarod42 sure, but note "The vector expected to be large enough, gigabytes". That's why I chose rather big vectors.

Comment: @alagner, thank you so much for both your time and effort here and showing a great tool in action! One concern on your `replaceElementsStl` is that you update `b` if 'pred' is `true` (line 74) and after that you apply std::next(b). In case the former returns `e` (past the container), the `std::next` will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @alagner, the main point here is if I somehow misled you with my question. I am not looking for optimization of this code (see the “*Please don't pay much attention to the code, no need to optimize it, it provided for explanation purposes only.*”); my question if there is some ready algorithm or simple combination of them.

Comment: @Jarod42, thank you for the input; is seems that I somehow misled all people here. :) You are totally right with your concern, but my idea is to check back if there is some ready to go `std` algorithm or simple combination of them. On the data, actually this works on text and I provided `int` just to simplify the example. On my data most of the cases are not repeating characters. I just need to illuminate sequences like "====", "----", etc. But in terms of this question I was just interested in the algorithm, so, please don't focus on the described task, it has many other specifics.

Comment: @alagner, I believe, the comment from *Jarod42* was not about the size itself, but about the probability of singular items and he is correct here (see my answer to him), but I never put this information as precondition because my question was not about the optimization, but about existence of ready to go solutions in `std`. So, you both are right and I still need another answer :)

Comment: You're right about the UB, I missed the possibility of find_if_not not finding anything. As for the optimization: it's hard to resist when having a working baseline to compare against;)

Comment: @alagner, if you like performance challenges, you might find interesting my research on [Incremental upper bound in sorted range](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289146/incremental-upper-bound-in-sorted-range/). Feel free to step in with you ideas and research approaches. Some days later I will come with another one (working on text parser which should benefit from multi-threading); if you like, I will share the link for collaboration. :)